# Making a javascript animation to move bullet icon following the half circle path

Tags: javascript, css

Im about to make animation in a navigation I made, the Idea is to move the bullet in a circle path when we hover the icon.

Im having no idea how to do it, is there the way to do it?

[image: round navigation]

Above is the navigation, I want the red dot move along the half circle path when we hover the button

Comment: I suppose I can get hint of what to do or the similar things like this so I can start learning. Even expert once a beginner, If I know I wouldnt ask in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with pure css. Codepen [demo](https://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/OQaQaa).
I used scss for simplifying the writing of code. Code snippet below uses compiled css code. Of course, you will need to adapt this code for your task. This is just a demonstration of the possibilities of css.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrap {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red inset;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red inset;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.menu:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #ff000040;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu__item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu__item:hover ~ .menu__pointer {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu__item:nth-child(1) {
  top: 114px;
  left: 25px;
}
.menu__item:nth-child(1):hover ~ .menu__pointer {
  transform: rotate(-8.5deg);
}
.menu__item:nth-child(2) {
  top: 147px;
  left: 50px;
}
.menu__item:nth-child(2):hover ~ .menu__pointer {
  transform: rotate(-51deg);
}
.menu__item:nth-child(3) {
  top: 159px;
  left: 90px;
}
.menu__item:nth-child(3):hover ~ .menu__pointer {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.menu__item:nth-child(4) {
  top: 147px;
  right: 50px;
}
.menu__item:nth-child(4):hover ~ .menu__pointer {
  transform: rotate(-129deg);
}
.menu__item:nth-child(5) {
  top: 114px;
  right: 25px;
}
.menu__item:nth-child(5):hover ~ .menu__pointer {
  transform: rotate(-171deg);
}
.menu__pointer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 10px;
  transition: transform ease .3s .6s;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: rotate(-9deg);
}
.menu__pointer:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu__item"></div>
    <div class="menu__item"></div>
    <div class="menu__item"></div>
    <div class="menu__item"></div>
    <div class="menu__item"></div>
    <div class="menu__pointer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```